# How to iterate over Orbit of PermutationGroup?

Tags: memory, algorithm, permutation, group-theory

Another day, another permutation group question.
I'm given a `g=PermutationGroup[...]`, and a list `l={1, 3, 3, 2, ...}`. I know I can compute the **entire orbit** of `l` under `g` using

```
orbit=GroupOrbits[g, {l}, Permute];
```

However, if the group orbit is large, then this might run out of memory.

**Is there a way to iterate over the orbit element-by-element without keeping the full orbit around?** Note that this excludes the naive implementation of GroupOrbit (as e.g. done by SymPy) that simply uses memoization with a hashmap to keep track of the already-computed orbit elements.

I'm happy with a pointer to a high-level algorithm (e.g. using a strong generating set or some such), but I was unsuccessful chasing one down.

Thanks!